# Python Tableau SDK, specified module could not be found

Tags: python-2.7, tableau-api

I am using Python 2.7.10 (32 bit) and the older dataextract API.  I would like to use the Tableau SDK.  I can install the SDK no problem but throw traceback errors when I attempt to import modules.  Has anyone else had this issue and if so what did you do to fix it?

[import tableausdk generates a WindowsError: [Error 126].  from tableausdk.Extract import * generates a No module named tableausdk.Extract](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQQvX.png)

Comment: Have you followed the instructions here?: http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/sdk/en-us/help.htm#SDK/tableau_sdk_using_python.htm%3FTocPath%3D_____4

Comment: Yup, everything flows fine up until bullet 5.  When I try to import modules I through out errors.  The last line of the traceback reads:  File "C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
WindowsError: [Error 126] The specified module could not be found

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same issue when using 2.7.10

I use these two import statements for all of my scripts requiring the SDK and it works.

```
from tableausdk import Extract as tde
from tableausdk import *
```

When you call the module you'll do something like this

```
with tde.Extract(nameOfExtractFile) as extract:
```

From here, you can use it how you would expect

```
extract.opentTable()
```

or

```
extract.addTable()
```

etc... 
Hope this helps